# Execute an application before log-in time forever in linux

Tags: linux, angstrom-linux

I am working on a BBB device running on an Angstrom image and the display panel is a 7 inch LCD cape. I want to start an application as soon as log-in message prompts means the application should get start automatically just after the booting. To achieve this I tried

1) To put my script files in /etc/init.d and linked the script with /etc/rc5.d as S99myscript  and then updated the rc.d
But it was not an successful attempt.

2) I changed the /etc/issue file a little bit and to invoke the script i appended myscript file in the last as this.

```
. /home/root/myscript
// tried it like this also
sh . /home/root/myscript
```

but this time also i couldn't get my desired result.
What's i am missing ? Or how can I get the result.
The service file
[image: The content of service file]

Status of service file
[image: The status of service file]

Comment: Any error messages anywhere? Does your script work at all, e.g. when started manually?

Comment: @Harald Yes whenever i start script manually I get the message written in the script. From my side script is working fine.

Comment: @Harald- I found that rcx.d method is not gonna work bcoz angstrom uses systemd method to start and stop services.
So i followed the same procedure and by looking into the booting process via serial port i came to know that my script is not getting invoked even via the system services.